# MySQL select data from multiple tables using parameter of one table

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I am trying to fetch data from 4 tables as below -

```
tblBookId -(shelfNo,BookId)
tblBookGenDetail - (BookId,Publish,Catogary,Rating)
tblPhysicalDetails - (BookId,BookWgt,BookPages,BookDia)
tblPriceTags-(BookId,India,US,UK,Aus)
tblBookAuthorDetails - (BookId,author,firstReleased,Reprints,authorRating)
```

Now I am trying to fetch the data of All books present in particular shelf using shelfNo. in tabBookId

I am using this query to get the data -

```
SELECT tblBookId.BookId ,tblBookGenDetail.* , tblPhysicalDetails.* , 
  tblPriceTag.* , tblBookAuthorDetails.*  
FROM tblBookId 
INNER JOIN tblBookGenDetail 
  ON tblBookId.BookId = tblBookGenDetail.BookId 
INNER JOIN tblPhysicalDetails 
  ON tblBookGenDetail.BookId = tblBookGenDetail.BookId 
INNER JOIN tblPriceTags 
  ON tblPriceTags.BookId = tblBookGenDetail.BookId 
INNER JOIN tblBookAuthorDetails 
  ON tblBookAuthorDetails.BookId = tblPriceTags.BookId 
WHERE (tblBookId.shelfNo = @shelfNo);
```

This query is running fine and creating all the columns without any errors but it is not showing any data .

I dont know whether I can retrieve data using this method or like what I wanted it . But i tried many ways in which this is the closer to solution.

Note - asterik sign were not visible before I just edited it . 
I types all the content here by myself so may be some syntex error found, but In my code it is working fine .

Comment: This is assuming that all books have gen details, physical details price tags and author details.  any record not existing in all 5 tables will not be included in results.  can you guarantee that the same book ID exists at least once in all 5 tables?

Comment: Yes, BookId is exist atleast once in all the tables. and result is not showing any of the tables data.

Comment: If one of the tables is empty you wont get data. Just for the exercise - try everything with **LEFT OUTER JOIN**. BTW, you can do the **JOIN** on **tblBookId** for all the tables. Also try this.

Comment: @ThrashBean I tried with JOIN on tblBookId for all the tables no effect.

Answer (score 1):

One issue with your query is in your `JOIN` to the `tblPhysicalDetails` table.  You need to be joining on it's bookid.

Change this:

```
INNER JOIN tblPhysicalDetails ON 
    tblBookGenDetail.BookId = tblBookGenDetail.BookId
```

To

```
INNER JOIN tblPhysicalDetails ON 
    tblPhysicalDetails.BookId = tblBookGenDetail.BookId
```

You may also need to look into using an `OUTER JOIN` instead of the `INNER JOINs` if all data isn't present in each table.  See the link below for more detail:

- [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: Thanks sgeddes , but it is just typo here. I am trying to understand OUTER JOIN. And every tables contains all bookId So i think it should retrieve data

Comment: @user3060948 note that `tblBookGenDetail.BookID` <> `tblPhysicalDetails.BookID`  The join is simply wrong based on some assumptions.

Comment: @user3060948 -- I would suggest trimming your query down if you're still having issues.  Start with just your `tblBookId` table, and remove all joins.  Do you get results?  If not, the `shelfno` isn't being found.  If you get results, add your joins back one at a time.  Or replace `INNER` with `OUTER` and see which has `NULL` records.

Comment: @sgeddes . Thanks for your all help. the way you suggested worked for me . I found the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, i wouldnt use all the join's.

What I normally use is:

```
$shelfno = '101';
SELECT BookId, shelfNo, Publish, Catogary, Rating, BookWgt, Bookpages, BookDia, India, US, UK, Aus, author, firstReleased, Reprints, authorRating
FROM tblBookId, tblBookGenDetail, tblPhysicalDetails, tblPriceTags, tblBookAuthorDetails
WHERE tblBookId.BookId = tblBookGenDetail.BookId 
AND tblBookId.BookId = tblPhysicalDetails.BookId
AND tblBookId.BookId = tblPriceTags.BookId
AND tblBookId.BookId = tblBookAuthorDetails.BookId
AND shelfNo = '$shelfno'
```

But thats what I prefer.

Btw: Did you know you got 'Catogary'? Just so you know...

Maybe you can use this if you understand what it does :). I'm happy to help if you need some explanation.

Comment: I don't agree, JOINS are standard SQL, your way is not. Sorry, I prefere JOINs.

Comment: @JiFus - Thanks , But I want to get data based on shelfNo , not by bookId . Do u have any other solution for that

Comment: @Trash I didn't say JOINS were no standard SQL, I made an answer at how I prefer to do things like this :).

Comment: @user3060948 You say you want to get data based on shelfNo, what do you mean by that? You want them ordered by shelfNo ?

Comment: @JiFus - I mean i want all the books data for particular shelf no. say  500 books have same shelfno 101 , so i will pass  shelf no 101 to get the data of all 500 books

Comment: $user3060948 I edited my query, is this what you mean?